# Python List append with respective index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need help on list append. I have to export it into CSV with the respective list index.

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = ['w', 'f', 'g']
lst3 = ['e', 'r', 't']

ap = []

ap.append((lst1, lst2, lst3))

output: [(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['w', 'f', 'g'], ['e', 'r', 't'])]
```

Expected output:

```
[('a', 'w', 'e')
 ('b', 'f', 'r')
 ('c', 'g', 't')]
```

I need to export to Excel via Pandas, please help.

```
 col1   col2    col3
 a       w       e
 b       f       r
 c       g       t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a list of tuples, not a list of a tuple of lists. For your result, you can use `zip` with unpacking to extract items in an iterable of lists by index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*(lst1, lst2, lst3))),
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

print(df)

  col1 col2 col3
0    a    w    e
1    b    f    r
2    c    g    t
```

Then export to Excel as you normally would:

```
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```